# Target last element of array for $set operation

Tags: mongodb

I need to set a field on the last element of an array in a document, like this

```
db.col.updateOne(
    {_id: ObjectId(...)},
    {$set: {
        'log.-1.activity': 'new_activity'
    }},
)
```

But it fails:

> Cannot create field '-1' in element

How can I do this?

Example document:

```
[
    {
        "_id": ...
        "name": ...
        "log": [
            {"activity": ...},
            {"activity": ...},
            {"activity": ...}
        ]
    }
]
```

In this example I'd try to set the `activity` field of the last entry in the `log` array for a given document with id `_id`

Comment: Can you post your schema of `col` collection, at least one records. and why are you trying to `-1`, is there multiple name inside the `logs` sub-documents ?